# Clang version confusion (OSX and Cmake)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang

I'm attempting to lock down the compiler version I use (for a number of reasons I won't go into). To do this, I'd like to check the version of the compiler on build using `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`.

On OSX CMake reports:

```
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION  7.0.2.7000181
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID       Clang
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER          /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
```

However, the version reported via terminal is:

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

This is true of:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ --version
clang --version
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

Why the discrepancy in version numbers as reported by CMake and the command line (for the same executable)?
And for the purposes of restricting to a particular compiler version, is `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` reliable?

Comment: Where is CMake reporting the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION`?

Comment: I'm forcing it to with this in the CMakeLists.txt file:
MESSAGE("Compiler is ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} version ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION} (at ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})")

Comment: That's very strange, because I get `Clang version 7.3.0.7030031` just now using your string. You might want to delete the CMake cache perhaps...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out CMake sets the compiler version in `CMakeFiles/3.5.0/CmakeCXXCompiler.cmake` (for version 3.5.0). Only by deleting this file and re-building is the correct compiler version reported (assuming you had a different one installed at some point).